# Is it a good idea to have multiple address tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I currently have multiple tables that need address fields but don't know if I should use one address table for clients, employees, branch, etc that uses some sort of associative table. or make multiple address tables for each one of those tables. any advice or help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess using a single table for storing address would be fine. You could add fields such as `model` and `model_id` that would hold model name and associated id such as `client` and `client_id` respectively.

Comment: maintain country, state, city and address table separately and link the address id into required clients, employess and branch tables

Comment: Your current setup is probably fine too.

Comment: I have seen some databases which hold the primary address with the customer record and have a separate table for other addresses which may override the primary address when some business rules apply. For example in banking the customer primary address is where the customer lives or incorporation address and another address in a second table exists for where a statement should be sent to (the business rule being send statement to address in second table)